# Linux: delete all directories with only one file and no subdirectories

Tags: linux

How can I delete all directories/subdirectories from a tree which match the following conditions:

1. Directory don't contain another subdirectory
2. Directory contain just one file matching this regex pattern: ^\d{10}.jpg$ (ten digits with .jpg extension)

Executing the following command will return the desired folders but will also return directories with subdirectories

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'set -- "$0"/*.jpg; [ $# -le 1 ]' {} \; -print
```

Comment: This question would probably have been more applicable to [Unix/Linux SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com), but I'm glad you got an answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People have a fascination with one-liners (even though one can write scripts of arbitrary lengths which often makes things clearer), so let me first compress it into a single line of Bash :-) :

```bsh
shopt -s globstar; for d in **/; do f=("$d"/*); [[ ${#f[@]} -eq 1 && -f "$f" && "${f##*/}" =~ ^[0-9]{10}\.jpg$ ]] && echo rm -r -- "$d"; done
```

where `echo` is a safeguard during testing.

The same code in an overly commented, more readable script version:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Enable double asterisk globbing (see `man bash`).
shopt -s globstar

# Loop through every subdirectory.
for d in **/; do
    # Glob a list of the files in the directory.
    f=("$d"/*)
    # If
    # 1. there is exactly 1 entry in the directory
    # 2. it is a file
    # 3. the file name consists of 10 digits with a ".jpg" suffix:
    if [[ ${#f[@]} -eq 1 && -f "$f" && "${f##*/}" =~ ^[0-9]{10}\.jpg$ ]]; then
        # `echo` to ensure a test run; remove when verified.
        echo rm -r -- "$d"
    fi
done
```

The matching is pure Bash (version ≥4), and I believe is not vulnerable to "tricky" file names, due to the globbing. By default it works from the current directory, but it could be modified to work on a given argument, a hardcoded path, etc.

---

**ADDITION**: To run in backwards globbing order of subdirectories to avoid having to do multiple iterations if this is a problem, one can first store the subdirectories in a variable and then traverse it backwards like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Enable double asterisk globbing (see `man bash`).
shopt -s globstar

# Glob every subdirectory.
subdirs=(**/)

# Loop directories in backwards lexical order to avoid multiple iterations.
for ((i=${#subdirs[@]}; i>0; --i)); do
    d=${subdirs[i-1]}
    # Glob a list of the files in the directory.
    f=("$d"/*)
    # If
    # 1. there is exactly 1 entry in the directory
    # 2. it is a file
    # 3. the file name consists of 10 digits with a ".jpg" suffix:
    if [[ ${#f[@]} -eq 1 && -f "$f" && "${f##*/}" =~ ^[0-9]{10}\.jpg$ ]]; then
        # `echo` to ensure a test run; remove when verified.
        echo rm -r -- "$d"
    fi
done
```

I think this will solve the issue in the comment, where some directories become eligible for removal only after the subdirectories have been handled (I will not update the one-liner, but everyone is free to do so for themselves :-) ).

Comment: It works, thanks. Is there any posibility to reverse the order in `for d in **/`? In many cases I have to run the script more times to remove nested directories which match the rules...

Comment: @SYNCRo: That seems like a reasonable addition for this functionality. See the updated answer for an approach.

Answer (score 0):

Save your command's output and this command's output:

```
ls -lR | awk -F: '!($0 ~ ORS "d") && $0 ORS ~ "-" {print $1}' RS=
```

(This one finds directories without subdirectories)

And use "comm" command to check similar lines maybe?

Comment: yeap, `comm` and `xargs` can do the job